# Sass styles don't work on localhost

Tags: css, sass, localhost

I struggle with following issue related proccessing Sass styles:

1. I created site with its directory on desktop;
2. I added contact form - for this purpose I moved site into localhost;
3. I renamed index.html into index.php in order to work with contact form;
4. Once index renamed, any of newly added SCSS styles are not updated;

Additionally I cleared .sass-cache - even this doesn't resolve issue.

Has anyone solution for this kind of issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **Please, make sure you did these two things perfectly**
>
> **1. Convertion of the SASS file .SCSS to .CSS** ( There are couples
>   of software, using the software you can convert sass file into .css file)
>
> **2. Carefully check the stylesheet link in your HTML file**

Comment: Zakirbd, I checked both first and second point, but my issue occurs when I change extension: *.html into *.php in index file. When I leave html extension it's fine. But I want to use contact form, so I want index.php file not index.html.

Comment: Can you show me PHP & SASS folders, HTML headers & problems screenshots

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TDJ23lleY_WvkFxRaKFGFMFVok-8s80K/view?usp=sharing <-- here is screenshot of main directory in htdocs folder. In folder sass I have only style.scss, and in css folder i have style.scss

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get it, If don't mind, can you show me the html head section screenshot & css folder screenshot.